# scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'CassandraSession.class'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cassandra, scalac, lagom

I've been developing in Javadsl with Maven, but I haven't been able to compile the project in my intellij 2016 since I added Scaladsl libraries.

This is the error I am getting:

> Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading
>   class file 'CassandraSession.class'. Could not access term session in
>   package akka.persistence.cassandra, because it (or its dependencies)
>   are missing. Check your build definition for missing or conflicting
>   dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic
>   classpath.) A full rebuild may help if 'CassandraSession.class' was
>   compiled against an incompatible version of
>   akka.persistence.cassandra.

I tried the followings:

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart the Intellij
2. Maven Clean Install (failed)
3. Restart the PC

None of them worked.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is my POM.xml for the module which I am using both Scaladsl and Javadsl.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste your `pom.xml` into the question?